# What does DBeaver shortcut Ctrl+Shift+- mean?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, dbeaver

I wanted to comment out the line in DBeaver, so I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> keys. But it didn't work. So I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and it worked in a wrong way: this shortcut opened the same query space, and when I pressed the same shortcut again - it has gone.

I googled it, but still don't know what is the name of this function.
What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortcut that you should be using to comment is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for a single line and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for multi line comment as per DBeaver [documentation](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Shortcuts/#sql-editor).

Coming to your question, they have not mentioned about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> it in their docs but it does open another another SQL editor window for you which indicates the purpose is just it.